# Unplugging laptop PSU from wox instead of wall socket

Tags: laptop, power-supply

My laptop PSU has 2 parts, one containing the brick with the cable going to the computer and the other one a cable with a standard IEC C13 connector and the wall plug.

I was wondering if there are any risk at disconnecting the PSU from the IEC C13 connector instead of the wall plug (because of the pandemic I have to move quite often with my computer and this would help my cable management without having to buy an other PSU).

Comment: No there is no additional risk and is essentially no different than unplugging from the socket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your power supply and laptop aren't going to see any difference if you unplug the C13 connector instead of the wall socket.  However, there are a couple safety  factors to keep in mind.

- The C13 connector probably isn't rated for as many plug/unplug cycles as a wall socket and may start to wear out with repeated use.  But it's going to be the cable side (C13), not the power supply side (C14) that wears, so you can just replace the cable if that happens.  But keep an eye on it and replace it if it starts to feel loose.  A loose mains connector can arc making it a fire risk.
- If you have small children in the house, an unplugged C13 connector could be a shock risk.  A C13 connector is easier to stick small metal objects in than some wall plugs such as the newer US tamper-resistent outlets.  And the end of the cable may also be more accessible to small children than the outlet.